# Get route name from URL containing subdomain

Tags: symfony, routes, subdomain

Symfony has method [`UrlMatcherInterface::match($pathinfo)`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcherInterface.php) which accepts URL path and returns information about it (e.g. route name, route parameters, action method and others). So if I call this method as `$matcher->match('/help')`, I get information about `http://example.com/help` URL.

The question: how do I can get information about URL containing subdomain, e.g. `http://subdomain.example.com/events`? This method accepts only path without hostname and it throws [`ResourceNotFoundException`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5129c4cf7e294b1a5ea30d6fec6e89b75396dcd2/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Exception/ResourceNotFoundException.php) when I try to pass URL with hostname.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using [RequestContext & UrlMatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html#usage).

```
$parsedUrl = parse_url($url);

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->setMethod($method); // e.g. GET
$context->setScheme($parsedUrl['scheme']);
$context->setHost($parsedUrl['host']);

$matcher = new UrlMatcher(
    $this->router->getRouteCollection(),
    $context
);

$routeInfo = $matcher->match($parsedUrl['path']);
```